# Xml parser function never gets called

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I'm currently working with swift and trying to make and RSS reader iOS iPhone app. I'm currently having trouble with calling the parser function. I'm really trying to replicate what I developed in Objective-C (which works well) with Swift.

This is my `tableView.swift class`

```
import UIKit

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
    var feeds: NSMutableArray = []
    var fItem = Dictionary<String, Float>()
    var fTitle: String = String()
    var element: String = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TouchCodeMagazine")
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
        parser.parse()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feeds.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {

        let CellId: NSString = "Cell"

        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell

        if let ip = indexPath {
            cell.textLabel.text = "hello\(ip.row)"
        }
        return cell
    }

   // This function is never called.
   func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, nameSpaceURI namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName: String!, attributes attributeDict: Dictionary<String, Float>) {

        element = elementName
        println(element) // This line is never executed.
    }
}
```

I have set the NSXMLParserDelegate but still it never gets called.

Any idea on what I can do to get this working? This is all the code I have so far. Maybe I need to import e certain framework?

Comment: im sorry but I don't get it either (and I tried it) -- you aren't missing frameworks, the url is valid, data can be loaded from it as well, the parser encounters no error (checked by println("\(parser.parserError)") after parse... I don't know but ... this looks like a bug to me

Comment: Thanks @Daij-Djan I'll keep investigating and see why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName: String!, attributes: Dictionary<String, Float>) {
    println(elementName) // This line is never executed.
}
```

Correction: Actually, it's not the last parameter, it's the spelling of `namespaceURI` vs. `nameSpaceURI` in your original.

Copied and pasted again out of working playground.

Comment: I just can't believe that it was all down to a misspelling :S Thanks though. Good pair programming :p